# FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions com.facebook.sdk, code = 2

Tags: ios, facebook, xcode5

Okay, when I try to open new session with publish permissions and pass array of permissions, facebook sdk pops up me an error. com.facebook.sdk code 2 error (which has a lot of explanations and I'm pretty sure that I tried almost everything from here).

That looks something like this:

```
permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions", @"publish_stream", nil];
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:permissions defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends allowLoginUI:YES
                                 completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                                     [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
                                 }];
```

if I say: permissions = nil; And call this same thing, everything works okay. After that, I am able to call same function WITH permissions and user is able to post directly on facebook (directly on wall). Am I missing something? 
I'm working with latest facebook sdk (3.8 I think) and testing on device with 6.1.4 version iOS.

Maybe I should try to call requestNewPublishPermissions for an active session after opening new session with nil permissions?

Comment: Is your app in sandbox ? if so - is the user you are trying to authroize is added as sandbox user ?

Comment: No, it's out of sandbox, it already have 50 test users and they are posting photos (app is working with nil permissions and users have to approve photos manually on their profile).